# find the interior, closure, and boundary

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$\ A  =\{(\tfrac{1}{m},\tfrac{1}{n})\in \mathbb{R}^2 : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}\}$

$\ C  =\cup\space B((\tfrac{1}{n},n),\tfrac{1}{n}) \space for\space n\in \mathbb{N}$

My claim is 
$\ int(A)  =\emptyset , cl(A) = A \cup  \{(0,\tfrac{1}{n}), n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}\} \cup \{(\tfrac{1}{m},0), m \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}\} \cup \{ (0,0)\}, \partial A=cl(A)$

But i think it is wrong at some point.

also, for the set C, i'm having a difficulty of finding it

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of $B$ by defining $C$? $[0,1/n)$, $(1/m,0]$ and $\{0\}$ are no subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. It looks sloppy.

Comment: The set $A$ does not depend on parameters, so neither does it's closure. Why do $m,n$ appear as free variables in your expression for $\operatorname{cl}(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you meant to say: $$\text{cl}A=A\cup\left\{ \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\right\} \cup\left\{ \left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\right\} \cup\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\} $$
If so then you are correct. You are also correct is saying that $\text{int}A=\emptyset$
(hence $\partial A=\text{cl}A$).

The definition of $C$ is unclear to me.